# Write-Statement depends on earlier Write-Statements?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Excuse me that the code I'm posting is no minimal example. When I try to further reduce the code, the situation I want to show you breaks down. I'm a beginner and simply cannot understand what is happening here.

Please scroll down to the Write-Statement "WTF".

Effect Number 1: The output of the Write statement that gives out "ctemp" to stdout is dependent on the earlier write statement giving out "WTF". Run the code, then comment out the "WTF" part and run again. How can this be?

Effect Number 2: The ctemp that is supposed to be written to stdout is last defined in the matmul-calculation. When I instead overwrite this result with a matrix full of 1's (as currently commented out), the output does NOT longer depend on an earlier WTF-Write-Statement.

I'm at a loss and cannot see any logic in this. What is going on? Thanks.

EDIT: as requested, I specify the differing output I get.

**WITH Write-Statement:**

WTF
0.40000000E+01   0.00000000E+00   0.20000000E+01   0.10000000E+01   0.10000000E+01   0.20000000E+01   0.20000000E+01   0.30000000E+01

**WITHOUT Write-Statement:**

0.22583338E+01  -0.17920885E+01   0.13104573E+01  -0.21149418E+01   0.28983440E+01   0.24774309E+01   0.37416662E+01   0.47920885E+01

**THE COMPILER:**

Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 12.0.3.174 Build 20110309

```
program testlapack
 implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
  integer :: n, ndim, k, j, i
  complex(dp) :: cunit, czero, cone

  complex(dp), allocatable :: H(:,:)          !Input Hamiltonian
  complex(dp), allocatable :: EigVec(:,:)     !Eigenvector matrix
  complex(dp), allocatable :: InvEigVec(:,:)  !Inverted eigenvector matrix
  complex(dp), allocatable :: EigVal(:)       !Eigenvalue vector
  complex(dp), allocatable :: ctemp(:,:)      !Temporary array
  complex(dp), allocatable :: ctemp2(:,:)      !Temporary array


!Lapack arrays and variables
  integer :: info, lwork
  complex(dp), allocatable :: work(:)       
  real(dp), allocatable :: rwork(:)    
  integer,allocatable :: ipiv(:)
  
  ndim=2
  lwork=ndim*ndim
    allocate(H(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(EigVec(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(EigVal(ndim))
    allocate(InvEigVec(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(ctemp2(ndim,ndim))


    H = reshape((/ (4,0), (1,2), (2,1), (2,3) /), shape(H))

  
   
   
     allocate(ctemp(ndim,ndim))
     ctemp(:,:) = H(:,:)
     allocate(work(lwork),rwork(2*ndim))
     call zgeev('N', 'V', ndim, ctemp, ndim, EigVal, InvEigVec, ndim, EigVec, ndim, work, lwork, rwork, info)
     if(info/=0)write(*,*) "Warning: zgeev info=", info
     deallocate(work,rwork)
     deallocate(ctemp) 
   
  
     InvEigVec(:,:)=EigVec(:,:)
     lwork = 3*ndim
     allocate(ipiv(ndim))
     allocate(work(lwork))
     call zgetrf(ndim,ndim,InvEigVec,ndim,ipiv,info)
     if(info/=0)write(*,*) "Warning: zgetrf info=", info   ! LU decomposition
     call zgetri(ndim,InvEigVec,ndim,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
     if(info/=0)write(*,*) "Warning: zgetri info=", info ! Inversion by LU decomposition (Building of InvEigVec)
     deallocate(work)
     deallocate(ipiv)



write(*,*) "WTF"
     
     allocate(ctemp(ndim,ndim))
     do i=1,ndim
        ctemp(i,i) = EigVal(i)
     end do
     ctemp2 = matmul(ctemp, InvEigVec)
     ctemp = matmul(EigVec,ctemp2)  

 !    ctemp = reshape((/ (1,1), (1,1), (1,1), (1,1) /), shape(H))

   


         do i=1, ndim
             do j=1, ndim
                write(*, '(2e17.8)', advance='NO') real(ctemp(i,j)), aimag(ctemp(i,j))
             end do
             Write(128,*)
         end do


   deallocate(H)
   deallocate(EigVal)
   deallocate(EigVec)
   deallocate(InvEigVec)
   deallocate(ctemp)
   deallocate(ctemp2)
  

end program testlapack
```

Comment: I get identical output with and without that `write` statement.

Why do you use `dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)` instead of `dp = kind(1.0d0)`?

I haven't checked on your LAPACK calls.

Comment: I too get the same values with & without the `write` statement. Perhaps you can give us compiler, OS, and your differing output?

Comment: I added the requested information. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I do get differing answers with & without, but my without answer is different than yours (and consistent with my gfortran-compiled output): `0.18390026E+01   0.12550191E+01  -0.11891761E+01   0.91347032E+00   0.19235920E+01   0.27412983E+00   0.41609974E+01   0.17449809E+01`

Comment: AlexE, use of selected_real_kind is the "preferred" way of choosing a kind that is independent of what the implementation's choice of "double precision" is. The idea is that you ask for a kind that has the properties you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer:

```
allocate(ctemp(ndim,ndim))
do i=1,ndim
   ctemp(i,i) = EigVal(i)
end do
ctemp2 = matmul(ctemp, InvEigVec)
ctemp = matmul(EigVec,ctemp2)
```

ctemp is a 2x2 (complex) matrix, but you have only defined the diagonals. If you initialize it to zero (or set `ctemp(1,2)=0.0; ctemp(2,1)=0.0`) you will get the same answer both times (and on both compilers):

```
0.40000000E+01   0.66613381E-15
0.20000000E+01   0.10000000E+01
0.10000000E+01   0.20000000E+01
0.20000000E+01   0.30000000E+01
```

Comment: +1 From the *Intel Fortran Language Reference*: "The storage space allocated is uninitialized unless SOURCE= is specified."

Comment: oh my god, I never would have found that. Thanks.